# Passing a variable that is inside a function to other function without changing its value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, indexof

I have 2 functions I would like to know how can I get the variable "foto" that generates a random number inside the function generate() to the function verify() because the indexOf will verify the number that was generated on the generate() function and will check if this value is in one of the arrays defined inside verify().

```
function generate() { 

    var score = document.getElementById('score');
    var foto  =   Math.floor(Math.random() *20) + 1;
    var fotoDOM = document.querySelector('.foto');
    fotoDOM.src = 'foto-' + foto + '.jpg';
    console.log(foto);
    document.getElementById('photo').style.animation ="appearPerson 1s";
    score.innerHTML = foto; 

}

document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', verify);     

function verify() {

    var yesMeetup = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15];
    var notMeetup = [16,17,18,19,20];
    var notButton = document.getElementById('no');
    var yesButton = document.getElementById('yes');
    var decisao = document.getElementById('decisao');
    debugger

    if (yesButton) {

        if (yesMeetup.indexOf(foto) ) {
            decisao.textContent = "You got it";
        } else if (notMeetup.indexOf(foto) ) {
            decisao.textContent = "wrong";
        }
    }

    else if (notButton) {

        if (notMeetup.indexOf(foto) ) {
            decisao.textContent = "You Gou it";
        } else if (yesMeetup.indexOf(foto) ) {
            decisao.textContent = "Wrong";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the foto variable outside of the `generate` function (which will make it global) and it will be available in the `verify` function.
I suggest you have a read about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```
var foto;
function generate(){ 

    var score = document.getElementById('score');
    foto = Math.floor(Math.random() *20) + 1;
    var fotoDOM = document.querySelector('.foto');
    fotoDOM.src = 'foto-' + foto + '.jpg';
    console.log(foto);
    document.getElementById('photo').style.animation ="appearPerson 1s";
    score.innerHTML = foto; 

}



document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', verify);     


function verify()
{


    var yesMeetup = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15];
    var notMeetup = [16,17,18,19,20];
    var notButton = document.getElementById('no');
    var yesButton = document.getElementById('yes');
    var decisao = document.getElementById('decisao');
    debugger
    if(yesButton){

        if(yesMeetup.indexOf(foto) ){

            decisao.textContent = "You got it";

        }else if(notMeetup.indexOf(foto) ){

            decisao.textContent = "wrong";
        }
    }

    else if (notButton){

        if(notMeetup.indexOf(foto) ){

            decisao.textContent = "You Gou it";


        }else if(yesMeetup.indexOf(foto) ){

            decisao.textContent = "Wrong";

        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: But if I do that the variable will no longer generate a random number when I click on the button which calling the function generate()

Comment: Every time generate is called it will assign a new value to the variable foto which is global and available in the verify function

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `foto` is required by the function `verify`, then that should be an argument of that function:

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var foto = generate();
    verify(foto);
});  

...

/**
 * Generate a thing.
 */
function generate() {
    ...
    return foto;
}

/**
 * Veryify the thing.
 * @param {Number} 
 */
function verify(foto) {
    ...
}
```

I would encourage you to insulate your functions as much as possible so that they don't really depend on outside variables. Maybe manipulating DOM is required inside one of them, but if you can abstract those things away from each other – DOM manipulation in 1 function or bit of code, and all other business logic in another set of functions, your code should be easier to read / write / debug.